# Spanning Tree Vs Minimum Spanning Tree

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Given an un-directed and connected graph $G$ and two spanning trees $T1$, and $T2$

whereas:

$T1$ is an MST and an ordered list of it's edges by their weight is: $ {a_1 <= a_2 ....=<a_n }$

$T2$ is a random spanning tree of $G$ and an ordered list of it's edges by their weight is: $ {b_1 <= b_2 ....=<b_n }$

I need to prove that for every edge $ a_i<= b_i$

I tried doing so by induction by got stuck. Any help will be appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a minimum spanning tree?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Algorithms